# How to change a dataframe from long to wide given that the value to distribute is non-numeric?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello moving from R to python, I would like to figure out how to change a Long format to a wide format, given that the value to distribute is a string or non-numeric

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

#### Example dummy data

```
dummy_data = {'process_id':  [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6],
    
    'purchase_date': ['2020-01-01', 
                      '2020-01-01',
                      '2020-01-01',
                      '2020-03-01',
                      '2020-03-02', 
                      '2020-03-04', 
                      '2020-07-04', 
                      '2020-07-04',
                      '2020-01-20'],
 'consumption_date': ['2021-02-01', 
                      '2021-02-01',
                      '2021-02-01',
                      '2021-03-01',
                      '2021-04-02', 
                      '2021-05-04', 
                      '2021-09-04', 
                      '2021-09-04',
                      '2021-08-04'],
    'discount_code': ['10',
                      '12', 
                      '11',
                      '13',
                      '90', 
                      '81', 
                      '82', 
                      '11',
                      '10']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame (dummy_data, columns = ['process_id','purchase_date','consumption_date','discount_code'])
```

#### Example dummy data output:

```
   process_id purchase_date consumption_date discount_code

0           1    2020-01-01       2021-02-01            10
1           1    2020-01-01       2021-02-01            12
2           1    2020-01-01       2021-02-01            11
3           2    2020-03-01       2021-03-01            13
4           3    2020-03-02       2021-04-02            90
5           4    2020-03-04       2021-05-04            81
6           5    2020-07-04       2021-09-04            82
7           5    2020-07-04       2021-09-04            11
8           6    2020-01-20       2021-08-04            10
```

#### So there might be N discount_codes for each process_id

What I want to achieve: If there are multiple discount_codes for one process_id, I would like to create N discount_code_columns

#### Example expected data

```
expected_data = {'process_id':  [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    
    'purchase_date': ['2020-01-01', 
                      '2020-03-01',
                      '2020-03-02', 
                      '2020-03-04', 
                      '2020-07-04',
                      '2020-01-20'],
 'consumption_date': ['2021-02-01', 
                      '2021-03-01',
                      '2021-04-02', 
                      '2021-05-04', 
                      '2021-09-04',
                      '2021-08-04'],
    'discount_code_1': ['10', '13',   '90',   '81', '  82',  '10'],
    'discount_code_2': ['12', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '11', np.nan,],
    'discount_code_3': ['11', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
    }
df2 = pd.DataFrame (expected_data, columns = ['process_id','purchase_date','consumption_date','discount_code_1','discount_code_2','discount_code_3'])
```

#### Example expected data output

```
   process_id purchase_date consumption_date discount_code_1 discount_code_2 discount_code_3
0           1    2020-01-01       2021-02-01              10              12              11
1           2    2020-03-01       2021-03-01              13             NaN             NaN
2           3    2020-03-02       2021-04-02              90             NaN             NaN
3           4    2020-03-04       2021-05-04              81             NaN             NaN
4           5    2020-07-04       2021-09-04              82              11             NaN
5           6    2020-01-20       2021-08-04              10             NaN             NaN
```

#### So what I tried was to user pandas pivot

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['process_id','purchase_date','consumption_date'], 
columns='process_id', values=['discount_code'], aggfunc='first')
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1.columns=df1.columns.tolist()


   process_id purchase_date consumption_date    1    2    3    4    5    6
0           1    2020-01-01       2021-02-01   10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1           2    2020-03-01       2021-03-01  NaN   13  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2           3    2020-03-02       2021-04-02  NaN  NaN   90  NaN  NaN  NaN
3           4    2020-03-04       2021-05-04  NaN  NaN  NaN   81  NaN  NaN
4           5    2020-07-04       2021-09-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   82  NaN
5           6    2020-01-20       2021-08-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   10
```

But that doesnt seem to be correct. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `unstack` to reshape after creating a `MultiIndex` to uniquely identify the rows

```
c = ['process_id', 'purchase_date', 'consumption_date']
df1 = df.set_index([*c, df.groupby(c).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)]).unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
```

---

```
>>> df1.reset_index()

   process_id purchase_date consumption_date discount_code_1 discount_code_2 discount_code_3
0           1    2020-01-01       2021-02-01              10              12              11
1           2    2020-03-01       2021-03-01              13             NaN             NaN
2           3    2020-03-02       2021-04-02              90             NaN             NaN
3           4    2020-03-04       2021-05-04              81             NaN             NaN
4           5    2020-07-04       2021-09-04              82              11             NaN
5           6    2020-01-20       2021-08-04              10             NaN             NaN
```

Comment: ya, if columns less like 10 it working nice, else better avoid `.astype(str)`

Comment: added dupe for alternative for avoid this

Comment: thx alot! could you pls elaborate [*c,.groupby(c).cumcount().add(1) that part a bit?

Comment: @Jacky Sure!  Here `*c` is used to unpack the list `c` basically we are using unpacking operator `*` to flatten the list in order to set the columns 'process_id', 'purchase_date', 'consumption_date' along with the create sequential counter as the index of dataframe.